# initialize javascript variable with angularjs scope variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How to initialize `javascript` variable with the value of `AngularJS` scope variable...

Something like:

```
xyz.controller(
(
$scope.country="Canada"; );
```

**javascript** :

```
<script>

var country = {{scope.country}};

</script>
```

Comment: `var country = $scope.country` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the angular js scope variables by using `$scope.scopeVariableName` 
In order to assign this to a javascript variable just by

```
var varibleName = $scope.scopeVariableName;
```

if you are using scope objects(using controllerAs syntax) in UI, we can assign this using `this` variable

```
var varibleName = this.scopeVariableName;
```

Example:

```
<div ng-controller="yourController">
     {{scopeVariableName}}
</div>
```

controller :

```
function yourControllerFunction($scope){

   $scope.scopeVariableName = "Canada";
   var variableName = $scope.scopeVariableName;
}

yourControllerFunction.$inject = ['$scope'];

angular.module('yourMainModule').controller('yourController', yourControllerFunction);
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>{{country}}</p>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var xyz = angular.module('app', []);

xyz.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.country = 'Canada';
  var country = $scope.country;
  jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 200);
});
```

Here is a Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/hHRPzDQKbtSUppzpxfI2?p=preview

Comment: How can i call a JQuery function in angularjs controller !! Also what will be the order of adding links to controller and jQuery script .

Comment: You will need to add jquery.js before angular.js. Calling jQuery for example `jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 200);`